# How can I include a compiled react js component from a compiled react js single page app?

Tags: reactjs

Usually, when I want to use a react js dependency, I install the dependency using npm, then include its source JPX in my source JPX, and then I compile the whole thing, my page + its dependencies into a single web pack.

I would like to include a dependency at run time. For example, I create my react js page, compile it, but it's code loads a compiled dependency and injects the component dynamically into a div of my page.

Is this possible? Is there an easy way of doing it?

Comment: You can interact through globals. You may notice that most third-party React libs are UMD modules, they are assigned to `window` when you load them in non-modular environment, including `React` itself. But it doesn't seem like a good way. Consider explaining your case, this may help.

Comment: I want components to be developed and published by third part. My use case is: the user has a yaml file listing the name of many components (from a limited set of components that obey an interface I define), and from this yaml file I dynamically inject such components into the user's page at run time. I wouldn't like to generate an app dynamically and run nodejs dynamically for that, but it seems it might be the only way...

Comment: The components in my use case would be complex and they might be one child of the other.

Comment: There certainly can be other ways. Basically it's either interacting through globals or using `System.import`. This depends on your relations with a third party. A cleaner solution would be to provide `@yournamespace/plugin` package to a party that contains `registerComponent` function and registers it in app container, so a party is responsible for registering own components.

Comment: The problem is not registering the components, the problem is the components contain html code, css, javascript, and also include dependencies (other components) which have these 3... So even if I call a javascript function, how can component creators bundle their components in a package I can load? 
I don't want to import JSX, I want to import the final result...

Comment: They can bundle it with Webpack, as you do. They create a project with create-react-app or clone existing template and bundle it with `npm run build`. Is there a problem with bundling?

Comment: If you build the component before hand, how do you include the already built component in your page? I don't know how to do that - if you do please provide an answer :D

I don't want to include the JSX, I want to use the compiled version of a component and insert it on a div in my page, for instance.

Comment: As I said above, UMD bundles are exposed as globals, so a component will be available on `window` in case it's loaded with <script>. I'll try to explain it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I didn't understand well what you meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application and plugin component that belong to different bundles can interact through global variables.

Once a plugin is bundled as UMD module, which is default choice for client-side library, its export is available as global variable specified in bundler configuration ([`output.library`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library) for Webpack), e.g. `SomePluginNamespace`.

Considering that plugin component is exported from plugin bundle:

```
export const SomePluginComponent = prop => ...;
```

And it's loaded before main bundle:

```
<script src="/plugin.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

It will be available as `window.SomePluginNamespace.SomePluginComponent` inside the application. `<script>` tags can be created programmatically by the application to load plugin bundles dynamically.

Another way to use globals is to provide plugin developer with a framework that takes care of plugin components, e.g. `my-app-plugin-registry` package:

```
const CONTAINER_SYMBOL = Symbol.for('my-app-plugins-container');

const container = window[CONTAINER_SYMBOL] = window[CONTAINER_SYMBOL] || {};

export const registerComponent = (name, Component) => container[name] = Component;

export const getComponent = (name) => container[name];
```

Plugin developer registers a component in own bundle:

```
import { registerComponent } from 'my-app-plugin-registry';

export const SomePluginComponent = registerComponent('SomePluginComponent', prop => ...);
```

Application developer accesses registered components with `getComponent` in another bundle. This requires to load plugin scripts prior to application script. Or in case plugin `<script>` is created dynamically, use `getComponent` only after plugin script was loaded.

Yet another way is to use script loader that is aware of JavaScript modules, notably SystemJS. Application bundle loads plugin bundles dynamically:

```
System.import('.../plugin.bundle.js').then(({ SomePluginComponent }) => { ... });
```

SystemJS should be configured to process UMD modules in plugin bundles correctly.

Comment: This looks like what I need! :D I will try with some examples this and get back here!