# why I am getting undefined while importing module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I make a custom button using `reactjs`, I follow the below link

https://github.com/davidcsejtei/custom-button

Now I bundle the `button` or `component` and try to use in `vanilla js` .

I also look into this question
[How can I include a compiled react js component from a compiled react js single page app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620989/how-can-i-include-a-compiled-react-js-component-from-a-compiled-react-js-single)

I bundle my component in `umd` format but able to include in script

here is my bundle

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidcsejtei/custom-button/master/dist/custom-button.js

I copy the bundle in `js` file and try to show that `component`.

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/xobikuzeku/edit?html,js,output

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    !function(e,t){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=t():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],t):"object"==typeof exports?exports["custom-button"]=t():e["custom-button"]=t()}(window,function(){return function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var o=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,n),o.l=!0,o.exports}return n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,r){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=n(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var r=Object.create(null);if(n.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var o in e)n.d(r,o,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,o));return r},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="",n(n.s=1)}([function(e,t,n){"use strict";e.exports=n(2)},function(e,t,n){"use strict";n.r(t),n.d(t,"default",function(){return l});var r=n(0),o=n.n(r);n(4);function i(e){return(i="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(e){return typeof e}:function(e){return e&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&e.constructor===Symbol&&e!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof e})(e)}function u(e,t){for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){var r=t[n];r.enumerable=r.enumerable||!1,r.configurable=!0,"value"in r&&(r.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(e,r.key,r)}}function c(e,t){return!t||"object"!==i(t)&&"function"!=typeof t?function(e){if(void 0===e)throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called");return e}(e):t}function f(e){return(f=Object.setPrototypeOf?Object.getPrototypeOf:function(e){return e.__proto__||Object.getPrototypeOf(e)})(e)}function a(e,t){return(a=Object.setPrototypeOf||function(e,t){return e.__proto__=t,e})(e,t)}var l=function(e){function t(){return function(e,t){if(!(e instanceof t))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}(this,t),c(this,f(t).apply(this,arguments))}var n,i,l;return function(e,t){if("function"!=typeof t&&null!==t)throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function");e.prototype=Object.create(t&&t.prototype,{constructor:{value:e,writable:!0,configurable:!0}}),t&&a(e,t)}(t,r["Component"]),n=t,(i=[{key:"render",value:function(){return o.a.createElement("button",null,"Custom button")}}])&&u(n.prototype,i),l&&u(n,l),t}()},function(e,t,n){"use strict";
        /** @license React v16.7.0
         * react.production.min.js
         *
         * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
         *
         * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
         * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
         */var r=n(3),o="function"==typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for,i=o?Symbol.for("react.element"):60103,u=o?Symbol.for("react.portal"):60106,c=o?Symbol.for("react.fragment"):60107,f=o?Symbol.for("react.strict_mode"):60108,a=o?Symbol.for("react.profiler"):60114,l=o?Symbol.for("react.provider"):60109,s=o?Symbol.for("react.context"):60110,p=o?Symbol.for("react.concurrent_mode"):60111,d=o?Symbol.for("react.forward_ref"):60112,y=o?Symbol.for("react.suspense"):60113,b=o?Symbol.for("react.memo"):60115,v=o?Symbol.for("react.lazy"):60116,h="function"==typeof Symbol&&Symbol.iterator;function m(e){for(var t=arguments.length-1,n="https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant="+e,r=0;r<t;r++)n+="&args[]="+encodeURIComponent(arguments[r+1]);!function(e,t,n,r,o,i,u,c){if(!e){if(e=void 0,void 0===t)e=Error("Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.");else{var f=[n,r,o,i,u,c],a=0;(e=Error(t.replace(/%s/g,function(){return f[a++]}))).name="Invariant Violation"}throw e.framesToPop=1,e}}(!1,"Minified React error #"+e+"; visit %s for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. ",n)}var g={isMounted:function(){return!1},enqueueForceUpdate:function(){},enqueueReplaceState:function(){},enqueueSetState:function(){}},j={};function w(e,t,n){this.props=e,this.context=t,this.refs=j,this.updater=n||g}function O(){}function S(e,t,n){this.props=e,this.context=t,this.refs=j,this.updater=n||g}w.prototype.isReactComponent={},w.prototype.setState=function(e,t){"object"!=typeof e&&"function"!=typeof e&&null!=e&&m("85"),this.updater.enqueueSetState(this,e,t,"setState")},w.prototype.forceUpdate=function(e){this.updater.enqueueForceUpdate(this,e,"forceUpdate")},O.prototype=w.prototype;var x=S.prototype=new O;x.constructor=S,r(x,w.prototype),x.isPureReactComponent=!0;var _={current:null,currentDispatcher:null},k=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,C={key:!0,ref:!0,__self:!0,__source:!0};function P(e,t,n){var r=void 0,o={},u=null,c=null;if(null!=t)for(r in void 0!==t.ref&&(c=t.ref),void 0!==t.key&&(u=""+t.key),t)k.call(t,r)&&!C.hasOwnProperty(r)&&(o[r]=t[r]);var f=arguments.length-2;if(1===f)o.children=n;else if(1<f){for(var a=Array(f),l=0;l<f;l++)a[l]=arguments[l+2];o.children=a}if(e&&e.defaultProps)for(r in f=e.defaultProps)void 0===o[r]&&(o[r]=f[r]);return{$$typeof:i,type:e,key:u,ref:c,props:o,_owner:_.current}}function E(e){return"object"==typeof e&&null!==e&&e.$$typeof===i}var R=/\/+/g,U=[];function $(e,t,n,r){if(U.length){var o=U.pop();return o.result=e,o.keyPrefix=t,o.func=n,o.context=r,o.count=0,o}return{result:e,keyPrefix:t,func:n,context:r,count:0}}function A(e){e.result=null,e.keyPrefix=null,e.func=null,e.context=null,e.count=0,10>U.length&&U.push(e)}function L(e,t,n){return null==e?0:function e(t,n,r,o){var c=typeof t;"undefined"!==c&&"boolean"!==c||(t=null);var f=!1;if(null===t)f=!0;else switch(c){case"string":case"number":f=!0;break;case"object":switch(t.$$typeof){case i:case u:f=!0}}if(f)return r(o,t,""===n?"."+M(t,0):n),1;if(f=0,n=""===n?".":n+":",Array.isArray(t))for(var a=0;a<t.length;a++){var l=n+M(c=t[a],a);f+=e(c,l,r,o)}else if(l=null===t||"object"!=typeof t?null:"function"==typeof(l=h&&t[h]||t["@@iterator"])?l:null,"function"==typeof l)for(t=l.call(t),a=0;!(c=t.next()).done;)f+=e(c=c.value,l=n+M(c,a++),r,o);else"object"===c&&m("31","[object Object]"==(r=""+t)?"object with keys {"+Object.keys(t).join(", ")+"}":r,"");return f}(e,"",t,n)}function M(e,t){return"object"==typeof e&&null!==e&&null!=e.key?function(e){var t={"=":"=0",":":"=2"};return"$"+(""+e).replace(/[=:]/g,function(e){return t[e]})}(e.key):t.toString(36)}function T(e,t){e.func.call(e.context,t,e.count++)}function I(e,t,n){var r=e.result,o=e.keyPrefix;e=e.func.call(e.context,t,e.count++),Array.isArray(e)?N(e,r,n,function(e){return e}):null!=e&&(E(e)&&(e=function(e,t){return{$$typeof:i,type:e.type,key:t,ref:e.ref,props:e.props,_owner:e._owner}}(e,o+(!e.key||t&&t.key===e.key?"":(""+e.key).replace(R,"$&/")+"/")+n)),r.push(e))}function N(e,t,n,r,o){var i="";null!=n&&(i=(""+n).replace(R,"$&/")+"/"),L(e,I,t=$(t,i,r,o)),A(t)}var B={Children:{map:function(e,t,n){if(null==e)return e;var r=[];return N(e,r,null,t,n),r},forEach:function(e,t,n){if(null==e)return e;L(e,T,t=$(null,null,t,n)),A(t)},count:function(e){return L(e,function(){return null},null)},toArray:function(e){var t=[];return N(e,t,null,function(e){return e}),t},only:function(e){return E(e)||m("143"),e}},createRef:function(){return{current:null}},Component:w,PureComponent:S,createContext:function(e,t){return void 0===t&&(t=null),(e={$$typeof:s,_calculateChangedBits:t,_currentValue:e,_currentValue2:e,_threadCount:0,Provider:null,Consumer:null}).Provider={$$typeof:l,_context:e},e.Consumer=e},forwardRef:function(e){return{$$typeof:d,render:e}},lazy:function(e){return{$$typeof:v,_ctor:e,_status:-1,_result:null}},memo:function(e,t){return{$$typeof:b,type:e,compare:void 0===t?null:t}},Fragment:c,StrictMode:f,Suspense:y,createElement:P,cloneElement:function(e,t,n){null==e&&m("267",e);var o=void 0,u=r({},e.props),c=e.key,f=e.ref,a=e._owner;if(null!=t){void 0!==t.ref&&(f=t.ref,a=_.current),void 0!==t.key&&(c=""+t.key);var l=void 0;for(o in e.type&&e.type.defaultProps&&(l=e.type.defaultProps),t)k.call(t,o)&&!C.hasOwnProperty(o)&&(u[o]=void 0===t[o]&&void 0!==l?l[o]:t[o])}if(1===(o=arguments.length-2))u.children=n;else if(1<o){l=Array(o);for(var s=0;s<o;s++)l[s]=arguments[s+2];u.children=l}return{$$typeof:i,type:e.type,key:c,ref:f,props:u,_owner:a}},createFactory:function(e){var t=P.bind(null,e);return t.type=e,t},isValidElement:E,version:"16.7.0",unstable_ConcurrentMode:p,unstable_Profiler:a,__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED:{ReactCurrentOwner:_,assign:r}},q={default:B},F=q&&B||q;e.exports=F.default||F},function(e,t,n){"use strict";
        /*
        object-assign
        (c) Sindre Sorhus
        @license MIT
        */var r=Object.getOwnPropertySymbols,o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,i=Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable;e.exports=function(){try{if(!Object.assign)return!1;var e=new String("abc");if(e[5]="de","5"===Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)[0])return!1;for(var t={},n=0;n<10;n++)t["_"+String.fromCharCode(n)]=n;if("0123456789"!==Object.getOwnPropertyNames(t).map(function(e){return t[e]}).join(""))return!1;var r={};return"abcdefghijklmnopqrst".split("").forEach(function(e){r[e]=e}),"abcdefghijklmnopqrst"===Object.keys(Object.assign({},r)).join("")}catch(e){return!1}}()?Object.assign:function(e,t){for(var n,u,c=function(e){if(null==e)throw new TypeError("Object.assign cannot be called with null or undefined");return Object(e)}(e),f=1;f<arguments.length;f++){for(var a in n=Object(arguments[f]))o.call(n,a)&&(c[a]=n[a]);if(r){u=r(n);for(var l=0;l<u.length;l++)i.call(n,u[l])&&(c[u[l]]=n[u[l]])}}return c}},function(e,t,n){var r=n(5);"string"==typeof r&&(r=[[e.i,r,""]]);var o={hmr:!0,transform:void 0,insertInto:void 0};n(7)(r,o);r.locals&&(e.exports=r.locals)},function(e,t,n){(e.exports=n(6)(!1)).push([e.i,"button {\n  border: 2px solid red;\n  padding: 10px;\n  background-color: #ccc; }\n",""])},function(e,t,n){"use strict";e.exports=function(e){var t=[];return t.toString=function(){return this.map(function(t){var n=function(e,t){var n=e[1]||"",r=e[3];if(!r)return n;if(t&&"function"==typeof btoa){var o=(u=r,"/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,"+btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(u))))+" */"),i=r.sources.map(function(e){return"/*# sourceURL="+r.sourceRoot+e+" */"});return[n].concat(i).concat([o]).join("\n")}var u;return[n].join("\n")}(t,e);return t[2]?"@media "+t[2]+"{"+n+"}":n}).join("")},t.i=function(e,n){"string"==typeof e&&(e=[[null,e,""]]);for(var r={},o=0;o<this.length;o++){var i=this[o][0];null!=i&&(r[i]=!0)}for(o=0;o<e.length;o++){var u=e[o];null!=u[0]&&r[u[0]]||(n&&!u[2]?u[2]=n:n&&(u[2]="("+u[2]+") and ("+n+")"),t.push(u))}},t}},function(e,t,n){var r,o,i={},u=(r=function(){return window&&document&&document.all&&!window.atob},function(){return void 0===o&&(o=r.apply(this,arguments)),o}),c=function(e){var t={};return function(e,n){if("function"==typeof e)return e();if(void 0===t[e]){var r=function(e,t){return t?t.querySelector(e):document.querySelector(e)}.call(this,e,n);if(window.HTMLIFrameElement&&r instanceof window.HTMLIFrameElement)try{r=r.contentDocument.head}catch(e){r=null}t[e]=r}return t[e]}}(),f=null,a=0,l=[],s=n(8);function p(e,t){for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e[n],o=i[r.id];if(o){o.refs++;for(var u=0;u<o.parts.length;u++)o.parts[u](r.parts[u]);for(;u<r.parts.length;u++)o.parts.push(m(r.parts[u],t))}else{var c=[];for(u=0;u<r.parts.length;u++)c.push(m(r.parts[u],t));i[r.id]={id:r.id,refs:1,parts:c}}}}function d(e,t){for(var n=[],r={},o=0;o<e.length;o++){var i=e[o],u=t.base?i[0]+t.base:i[0],c={css:i[1],media:i[2],sourceMap:i[3]};r[u]?r[u].parts.push(c):n.push(r[u]={id:u,parts:[c]})}return n}function y(e,t){var n=c(e.insertInto);if(!n)throw new Error("Couldn't find a style target. This probably means that the value for the 'insertInto' parameter is invalid.");var r=l[l.length-1];if("top"===e.insertAt)r?r.nextSibling?n.insertBefore(t,r.nextSibling):n.appendChild(t):n.insertBefore(t,n.firstChild),l.push(t);else if("bottom"===e.insertAt)n.appendChild(t);else{if("object"!=typeof e.insertAt||!e.insertAt.before)throw new Error("[Style Loader]\n\n Invalid value for parameter 'insertAt' ('options.insertAt') found.\n Must be 'top', 'bottom', or Object.\n (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#insertat)\n");var o=c(e.insertAt.before,n);n.insertBefore(t,o)}}function b(e){if(null===e.parentNode)return!1;e.parentNode.removeChild(e);var t=l.indexOf(e);t>=0&&l.splice(t,1)}function v(e){var t=document.createElement("style");if(void 0===e.attrs.type&&(e.attrs.type="text/css"),void 0===e.attrs.nonce){var r=function(){0;return n.nc}();r&&(e.attrs.nonce=r)}return h(t,e.attrs),y(e,t),t}function h(e,t){Object.keys(t).forEach(function(n){e.setAttribute(n,t[n])})}function m(e,t){var n,r,o,i;if(t.transform&&e.css){if(!(i="function"==typeof t.transform?t.transform(e.css):t.transform.default(e.css)))return function(){};e.css=i}if(t.singleton){var u=a++;n=f||(f=v(t)),r=w.bind(null,n,u,!1),o=w.bind(null,n,u,!0)}else e.sourceMap&&"function"==typeof URL&&"function"==typeof URL.createObjectURL&&"function"==typeof URL.revokeObjectURL&&"function"==typeof Blob&&"function"==typeof btoa?(n=function(e){var t=document.createElement("link");return void 0===e.attrs.type&&(e.attrs.type="text/css"),e.attrs.rel="stylesheet",h(t,e.attrs),y(e,t),t}(t),r=function(e,t,n){var r=n.css,o=n.sourceMap,i=void 0===t.convertToAbsoluteUrls&&o;(t.convertToAbsoluteUrls||i)&&(r=s(r));o&&(r+="\n/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,"+btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(o))))+" */");var u=new Blob([r],{type:"text/css"}),c=e.href;e.href=URL.createObjectURL(u),c&&URL.revokeObjectURL(c)}.bind(null,n,t),o=function(){b(n),n.href&&URL.revokeObjectURL(n.href)}):(n=v(t),r=function(e,t){var n=t.css,r=t.media;r&&e.setAttribute("media",r);if(e.styleSheet)e.styleSheet.cssText=n;else{for(;e.firstChild;)e.removeChild(e.firstChild);e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(n))}}.bind(null,n),o=function(){b(n)});return r(e),function(t){if(t){if(t.css===e.css&&t.media===e.media&&t.sourceMap===e.sourceMap)return;r(e=t)}else o()}}e.exports=function(e,t){if("undefined"!=typeof DEBUG&&DEBUG&&"object"!=typeof document)throw new Error("The style-loader cannot be used in a non-browser environment");(t=t||{}).attrs="object"==typeof t.attrs?t.attrs:{},t.singleton||"boolean"==typeof t.singleton||(t.singleton=u()),t.insertInto||(t.insertInto="head"),t.insertAt||(t.insertAt="bottom");var n=d(e,t);return p(n,t),function(e){for(var r=[],o=0;o<n.length;o++){var u=n[o];(c=i[u.id]).refs--,r.push(c)}e&&p(d(e,t),t);for(o=0;o<r.length;o++){var c;if(0===(c=r[o]).refs){for(var f=0;f<c.parts.length;f++)c.parts[f]();delete i[c.id]}}}};var g,j=(g=[],function(e,t){return g[e]=t,g.filter(Boolean).join("\n")});function w(e,t,n,r){var o=n?"":r.css;if(e.styleSheet)e.styleSheet.cssText=j(t,o);else{var i=document.createTextNode(o),u=e.childNodes;u[t]&&e.removeChild(u[t]),u.length?e.insertBefore(i,u[t]):e.appendChild(i)}}},function(e,t){e.exports=function(e){var t="undefined"!=typeof window&&window.location;if(!t)throw new Error("fixUrls requires window.location");if(!e||"string"!=typeof e)return e;var n=t.protocol+"//"+t.host,r=n+t.pathname.replace(/\/[^\/]*$/,"/");return e.replace(/url\s*\(((?:[^)(]|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*)\)/gi,function(e,t){var o,i=t.trim().replace(/^"(.*)"$/,function(e,t){return t}).replace(/^'(.*)'$/,function(e,t){return t});return/^(#|data:|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|file:\/\/\/|\s*$)/i.test(i)?e:(o=0===i.indexOf("//")?i:0===i.indexOf("/")?n+i:r+i.replace(/^\.\//,""),"url("+JSON.stringify(o)+")")})}}])});
</script>
<div id="f">hrlll</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('f').innerHTML = window['custom-button'].CustomButton
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

issue present in this line `document.getElementById('f').innerHTML = window['custom-button'].CustomButton`

any update ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly why, I couldn't find anything in the documentation about ids' lengths, but it seems your id isn't unique enough, try at least 2 or 3 characters characters. In real life, your id should be should be specific enough, I would try something like: id="root"